# Extract all the 'a' tags with in which 'img' tag resides, using php but i am not able to figure it out

Tags: php

Here is the code snipet being used:

```
$urlContent = file_get_contents('http://www.techeblog.com/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($urlContent);
$domPath=new DOMXpath($dom);
$linkList = $domPath->evaluate("/html/body/a/img");
foreach ($linkList as $link) 

  {

        echo $link->getAttribute("src")."<br />";   

  }
```

Need to extract all the links in which the child node is an image tag.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath expression will only return image tags that are inside links that are direct children of the body tag. If you want all link tags that contain images anywhere in the document, use the expression //a[img]

That being said, you may want to be more specific about which images you pull. This expression will limit the results to links containing images that are inside the blog entries //div[@class="entry"]//a[img].

Here is a great [XPath cheat sheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<?php

$urlContent = file_get_contents('http://www.techeblog.com/');

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($urlContent);

$domPath=new DOMXpath($dom);

$linkList = $domPath->evaluate('//div[@class="entry"]//a[img]');

foreach ($linkList as $link)
{
    echo $link->getAttribute("href").PHP_EOL;
}
```

Also, your echo is looking for an attribute calles *src*, which will not be present in the links.